# Protractor console log

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to output the text of a div in my protractor test, so far I have:

```
console.log(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('view-container')).getText());
```

but this outputs

```
[object Object]
```

I tried "toString()" and same result.

Is there a way to output the text to the console?

Comment: Can you create a async function and then put a await when assigning it to a variable and use that variable?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`getText` and most other Protractor methods return promises. You want to put your `console.log` statement inside the promise resolution:

Using the new Protractor syntax:

```
element(by.id('view-container')).getText().then(function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: How to wrap this in a (synchronous) page object?

Comment: wrap it in a sync page object by using browser.wait(function(){element(selector).getText().then(function(text){console.log(text)});}), timeoutms);

Answer (score 33):

this is pretty old, but as a former n00b at protractor, I wished there was more documentation.

you could also use:

```
element(by.id('view-container')).getText().then(console.log);
```

or what I like to do for readability is put all the objects on a page in their own function, section, or file:

```
//top declaration of variables
var viewContainer = element(by.id('view-container')).getText();

.... //bunch of code
....

viewContainer.then(console.log);
```

That will take care of most of your garden-variety debugging needs.

For promises in general, you could try using `protractor.promise.all()`

let's say you have two things that are both promises:

```
var getTime      = element(by.xpath(theTimeXpath)).getText();
var getPageTitle = element(by.xpath(thePageTitle)).getInnerHtml();

protractor.promise.all([getTime, getPageTitle]).then(function(theResultArray){

  var timeText           = result[0];
  var pageTitleInnerHtml = result[1];

   console.log(timeText);           // outputs the actual text
   console.log(pageTitleInnerHtml); //outputs the text of the Inner html
});
```

This second method is useful for when things begin to get more complex.  personally, however, I find other ways around this.  Although it's not bad, it's kind of funky for other developers having to read my code.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to suggest a small improvement to other answers.

**short answer** : I like to use `browser.sleep(0).then(..);` where I need to push something to protractor's flow.

it is generic and easy to move around.

**tl;dr**

so using the above, you can easily add a function on browser (or ptor) something like:

```
browser.log = function( logger, level, msg ){
     browser.sleep(0).then(function(){ logger[level](msg); });
}
```

or something a bit more sophisticated with `apply` - but that depends on your logger.

you can obviously enhance that a bit to have logger like api

```
var logger = browser.getLogger('name');
```

should be implemented like (lets assume log4js)

```
browser.getLogger = function( name ){
        var logger = require('log4js').getLogger(name);

        function logMe( level ) {
                 return function(msg ){
                      browser.sleep(0).then(function(){ logger[level](msg); });
                 }

        }

        return { info : logMe('info'), ... }
}
```

basically, the sky is the limit.

I am sure there's a way to make my code a lot shorter, the point is using the `sleep` method as basis.

Comment: That is completely cheating. Why not use the actual function to put it on the control flow? `browser.controlFlow().execute(function() { ... });`

Comment: @mvndaai i wouldn't call it cheating. It is not elegant. I agree. The reason why i like using sleep is because `controlFlow` to me is a private case where sleep is 0.

Answer (score 2):

You could always assert that the text you get is the text you expect:

`expect(element(by.id('view-container')).getText()).toBe('desired-text');`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
const textInfo = element(by.id('view-container'));
console.log('text: ', textInfo.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

When user wants to log the expected and actual result in protractor always use then method implementation.

```
verifyDisplayedText(locator: Locator, expectedText: string) {
const text = this.getText(locator);
try {
text.then(function(value){
if (value.trim() === expectedText) {
verifyLog("VERIFICATION: PASSED. Expected: '" + expectedText + "' Actual: '" + value+"'");
} else {
errorLog("VERIFICATION: FAILED. Expected: '" + expectedText + "' Actual: '" + value+"'");
}
});
expect(text).toBe(expectedText);
}catch (error1) {
errorLog("VERIFICATION: FAILED. Expected: '" + expectedText + "' Actual: '" + text+"'");
throw error1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## If you're in 2021, you will want to read this answer

According to protractors documentation, [.getText()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) returns a promise. Promise is an Object is javascript. So this is what you're logging.

You need to get the value off the promise, by resolving it

The best way to handle a promise, as of 2021, is to use `async/await` keywords. This will make Protractor 'freeze' and wait, until the promise is resolved before running the next command

```
it('test case 1', async () => {
  let text = await ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('view-container')).getText();
  console.log(text);
  // or directly
  console.log(await ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('view-container')).getText(););
})
```

`.then()` can also be used, but using `async/await` will make your code a lot more readable and easier to debug.