# Protractor- ElementFinder returning unexpected values

Tags: protractor

I am writing a protractor test case to compare the name(s) of the displayed data is same as the searched name.

Even though my test case works fine, I am not able to understand what is happening. Because when i expect the name to compare, it compares as expected, but when i print the elementFinder's(rowData)[(i have attached the output screen shot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fapR.png) value in console.log, it show a huge list of some values which i am not able to understand?

PS: I am a newbie to protractor`

```js
This is the testCase:

it('should show proper data for given last name', function () {
            var searchValue='manning';
            searchBox.sendKeys(searchValue);
            search.click();
            element.all(by.binding('row.loanNumber')).count().then(function(value) {
                var loanCount = value;
                for (var i = 0; i < loanCount; i++) {
                    var rowData = element.all(by.binding('row.borrowerName')).get(i).getText();
                    expect(rowData).toMatch(searchValue.toUpperCase()); 
                    console.log(rowData,'*****',searchValue.toUpperCase());
                    
                }
            });
        });`
```

And give me valuable suggestions about my style of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor console log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941739/protractor-console-log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowData` is a promise (not a value), so when you console.log it, you get the promise object

Protractor patches Jasmine to automatically resolve promises within the `expect()`, so that's how it knows to resolve the value and compare to the expected result.

If you want to console.log the value, you need to resolve the promise with `.then()` to get the value.

`rowData.then(function(rowDataText) {
    console.log(rowDataText);
  )}`

This is pretty much everyone's first question when they start using protractor. You will want to learn how promises work if you want a good understanding of how to manipulate them.