# Unable to run protractor test script using typescript

Tags: typescript, promise, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to run a protractor test script which is written in typescript. But when I do so, I get '**ManagedPromise**' in return. It doesn't show any error, just the 'ManagedPromise' in return

My Typescript test:

```
   //import {describe, it} from "selenium-webdriver/testing";
import {browser, by, element} from "protractor";

describe("For testing purpose", () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
        browser.get("https://angularjs.org");
        element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first 
        protractor test');
        element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();
        let title = browser.getTitle();
        console.log(title);
    });
});
```

My conf.js file:

```
  import {browser} from "protractor";

  exports.config = {

    directConnect: true,
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    framework: 'jasmine2',

    specs: ['./JSfiles/appExample.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 9000
        /* getPageTimeout: 3000,
         allScriptsTimeout: 2000*/
    },

    onPreapre: () => {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
};
```

My package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "typescript-dev-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "jasminewd2": "^2.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

My tsconfig.json file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
/* Basic Options */
"target": "es5",                          
"module": "commonjs",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"strict": true,
"outDir": "./JSfiles",
```

The response I get when I try to run the test:

```
   Started
ManagedPromise {
  flow_:
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_:
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::101',
        flow_: [Circular],
        tasks_: [Array],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        subQ_: null,
        state_: 'new',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
     taskQueues_: Set { [TaskQueue] },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     hold_:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [TimersList],
        _idleStart: 1694,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 2147483647,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 109,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 104 } },
  stack_: null,
  parent_:
   ManagedPromise {
     flow_:
      ControlFlow {
        propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
        activeQueue_: [TaskQueue],
        taskQueues_: [Set],
        shutdownTask_: null,
        hold_: [Timeout] },
     stack_: null,
     parent_:
      ManagedPromise {
        flow_: [ControlFlow],
        stack_: null,
        parent_: [ManagedPromise],
        callbacks_: [Array],
        state_: 'pending',
        handled_: true,
        value_: undefined,
        queue_: null },
     callbacks_: [ [Task] ],
     state_: 'pending',
     handled_: true,
     value_: undefined,
     queue_: null },
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  value_: undefined,
  queue_: null }
```

Comment: You are console.logging a promise.  You need to resolve it.

Comment: @Gunderson : yes, It's similar to this one. I tried searching for this issue. But I didn't get the question. So that's why I myself posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Gunderson** said in comments: `You are console.logging a promise. You need to resolve it`
This occurs at this code segment:

```
let title = browser.getTitle();
console.log(title);
```

In order to resolve  this, you can do

```
browser.getTitle().then(function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});
```

[Protractor console log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941739/protractor-console-log) has a more in depth explanation.

How to perform with async:

```
it('should pass', async() => {
  //other codez here
  let title = await browser.getTitle();
  console.log(title);
}
```

Comment: it may also be worth considering placing async before the () nd then saying let title = await browser.getTitle();

Comment: @BenMohorc: Yeah, you are right. It was happening because of the way I was using the console.log. After putting it inside the function it worked. Thanks !!

Comment: @JeremyKahan: Yeah, I have not placed async. I will put it in 'browser.getTitle'. Thanks!!

Comment: await goes before browser.getTitle(). async precedes "function" (which is not actually spelled out in the arrow notation). Probably that is what you meant. If you do that, you should not need this whole .then structure (which is not a criticism of the current answer, just an alternative)

Comment: @JeremyKahan I added the way to perform the same operation with async. Thanks for suggestion.